# The probability of probability

Tags: statistics

I am trapped by a logic premise. We know coins have no memory and each throw is a independent event. Thus, after 20 faces, it should not really matter what side you bet.

But there is also a normal distribution, and the probability of getting far to the mean. Isn´t there some sort of statistical tendency for returning to the mean? A black swan or something? The roulette record is 35 reds. If you happen to be in the 36th red in 2016, its exactly the same betting on both colors when you know the casuality is probably not gonna continue? Indeed, ine empirical terms a series of 50 reds in contrast to another random pattern is so unusual that im sure any scientist would believe the roulette is not working well, but all permutations are equally probable in the end.

Isn´t some kind of marginal probability as soon as you get far from the mean? Is it eqully probable to get a face in the next 5 tries when you are at throw 0 than when you are at 25?

Is it equally probable a particular random pattern of crosses and faces that 20000 faces in a row? Mathematically, an infinite or infinite -1 series of faces is possible. But whats the probability of not being equally distirbuted after 30,3000,30000 throws?

Answer (score 1):

Dice and coins indeed have no memory; in fact, if I show you a coin, you even don't know how many tosses before there was a "face". Is the coin smarter than you?

Note that if you throw a die 5 times, then the outcome $(4,2,5,1,6)$ has exactly the same probability as $(6,6,6,6,6)$. The normal distribution can be derived purely combinatorially: you can just count how many 6-tuples contain "one six", how many contain "two sixes" etc.

You can check all of your questions and concerns yourself, by running a simple simulation.

Of course, with a real die, if you throw it 10 times and you get 10 times a "six", then it is very likely that the eleventh will be a "six" too, that is, the die is not fair.

Comment: Exactly. *In real life*, the greater the number of times you get a specific option, the greater the probability that the object being used is biased in some form or the other. In the mathematical world, an object considered to be fair (not biased in any way) is exactly what it is – fair. In this case, it doesn't matter if you get $5$ or $500$ of the same option in a row, however unlikely that may be; the probabilities of the set of outcomes of the subsequent trial has the same values as that of the first, or second, or $n$th trial.

Comment: You misunderstand, having ten 6's in a row on a die that the probability of a 6 is unknown, it means it is more likely that your die is unfair (you might expect it to be a loaded die) but if it is indeed fair, given a large enough sample size you will see that the ten 6's in a row was just a fluke.

Comment: Whats the probability of a fair contest to behave as not fair after n tending infinite

Comment: Lets put it that way. How many reds do you need to watch in a row before you bet the roulette is unfair?

Comment: Take that number and ask yourself, provided the roulette is fair, the probability of a black increasing after a trial of that n-1 tries being red

Comment: @Whimusical Probably five times for me? Because I don't really watch it often... ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a common dilemma when people are first learning probability. Here's an example to help make some sense of it

If you do a large number of 15 coin flip trials, collect all of the trials where the first five coin flips were heads and call that set of coin flips $A$

When you look at the $A$ you will see that in the last ten coin flips will have on average five heads and five tails, and in total 10 heads and 5 tails. This isn't really counterintuitive, since in this set heads has a five flip advantage even though in the set of coin flips as a whole it was random that those five flips happend.

Comment: What if n times tends to infinite?

Comment: That is the ideal situation, since we want a large sample size

Comment: Indeed we shoul do the experiment only for those results that happened to be cross (e.g) during n first trials

Comment: So if we recorded a trillion trials of series of 1000. would 1000 crosses show with the same frequency as a more equally distribution pattern?

Comment: If I understand correctly yes, however there are far more "more equally distributed" patterns so you will have more of them, but any individual pattern will appear as often as 1000 crosses

Comment: Then the roulette has been spined 35 times in a row for 34000 milions times statistically in all history according to Guiness record. And that not considering roulettes are far from perfect, especially one from more than 50 years old